# php array loop with sub loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I would like to process an array in PHP to generate a new one.

The case is that I have an array with sales request and want to generate ticket request from that.

The issue I have is that depending on the type of sales request, 1 or more tickets are requered to be generated. If more tickets are requered, the only difference is the ticket number has a suffix of -1 or -2 added to the general ticket number.

I could do a foreach on the array and then a IF / ELSE if on the sales type and then set all the new array keys (which are all the same except for the ticket number)

But because I have many sales requests / lines this would be hard to maintain and I think not good for performance.

Example "semi" code:

```
$ticket = array (); 

foreach ( $input as $k=>$v )
{   
    $ticket[$k] ['exp_date']  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($input[$k] ['sales_date'])) );
    $ticket[$k] ['ticket_number']  = input[$k] ['ticketnumber']; // if 1 day, ticket number, if 2 days ticket number +  '-2' If multiple tickets are used, the first ticket should also have '-1'
    $ticket[$k] ['ticket_type']  = $input[$k] ['product'];
    $ticket[$k] ['sales_date']  = $input[$k] ['sales_date'];
    $ticket[$k] ['sales_ticket_number']  = $input[$k] ['ticket_number']  ;
    $ticket[$k] ['days']  = '0'; // not yet in use
    $ticket[$k] ['days_remaining']  = '0'; // not yes in use
}   

// if 

// if ($input[$k] ['product'] == '1-day') { $loop is null}
// elseif ($input[$k] ['product'] == '2-days') { $loop is 2}
// elseif ($input[$k] ['product'] == '3-days') { $loop is 3}
```

Suggestions / tips are much appreciated !

/EDIT

Flow logic without code and sub-optimal:

```
foreach ($input as $k=>$v) 
{
if ( $input[$k] ['product'] == '1-day')
{
  create new lines in new array
}
else if ( $input[$k] ['product'] == '2-days')
{
loop 2 times
create same entries, but ticket number = ticketnumber-1 and second loop ticketnumber-2
}
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the `$input` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want something like this:

```
$ticket = array (); 

foreach ( $input as $k=>$v )
{   
        // add the shared data for all tickets of one product to temporary ticket
        $temp_ticket['exp_date']  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($input[$k] ['sales_date'])) );
        $temp_ticket['ticket_type']  = $input[$k]['product'];
        $temp_ticket['sales_date']  = $input[$k]['sales_date'];
        $temp_ticket['sales_ticket_number']  = $input[$k]['ticket_number']  ;
        $temp_ticket['days']  = '0'; // not yet in use
        $temp_ticket['days_remaining']  = '0'; // not yes in use

       // get 'product' and retrieve the number of days
       $days = (int) $input[$k]['product']; // '1-day' becomes 1, '2-days' becomes 2, ...
       for ($d = 1; $d <= $days; $d++) {
           // loop through the number of days and add to ticket array
           // creates one ticket for each day of a product
           $ticket[$k . '-' . $d] = $temp_ticket;
           $ticket[$k . '-' . $d]['ticket_number']  = input[$k]['ticketnumber'] . '-' . $d;
       }
}
```

Notes: `$ticket[$k]` (as in your code) can't be used multiple times since the data would be overwritten. That's why I used `$ticket[$k . '-' . $d]` to generate one ticket entry for each day of each sale. Since the rest of the ticket data seems to be the same, I can generate the temp ticket before and make copies in the for loop.

Example of input:

```
$input = array(
  'order_1234' => array(
    'sales_date' => '2013-12-31',
    'product' => '1-day',
    'ticket_number' => '1234',
  ),
  'order_5678' => array(
    'sales_date' => '2014-03-31',
    'product' => '3-days',
    'ticket_number' => '5678',
  ),
  ...
);
```

My code would produce output like this

```
$ticket = array(
  'order_1234-1' => array(
    'exp_date' => '2014-12-31',
    'sales_date' => '2013-12-31',
    'ticket_type' => '1-day',
    'sales_ticket_number' => '1234',
    'days' => '0',
    'days_remaining' => '0',
    'ticket_number' => '1234-1',
  ),
  'order_5678-1' => array(
    'exp_date' => '2015-03-31',
    'sales_date' => '2014-03-31',
    'ticket_type' => '3-days',
    'sales_ticket_number' => '5678',
    'days' => '0',
    'days_remaining' => '0',
    'ticket_number' => '5678-1',
  ),
  'order_5678-2' => array(
    'exp_date' => '2015-03-31',
    'sales_date' => '2014-03-31',
    'ticket_type' => '3-days',
    'sales_ticket_number' => '5678',
    'days' => '0',
    'days_remaining' => '0',
    'ticket_number' => '5678-2',
  ),
  'order_5678-3' => array(
    'exp_date' => '2015-03-31',
    'sales_date' => '2014-03-31',
    'ticket_type' => '3-days',
    'sales_ticket_number' => '5678',
    'days' => '0',
    'days_remaining' => '0',
    'ticket_number' => '5678-3',
  ),
  ...
);
```

Comment: I'm still looking at this answer. Not sure if i understand it quite yet. The goal is that is the ticket_type is for example "2-days" then i need 2 lines in the new array ($ticket). So 1 line for 1day tickets and multiple lines for tickets of another type.

Comment: That's exactly what happens in my code. I'll add some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: It works :) thanks very much. I changed the $days part as I found that the product could have a number that does not represent the number of tickets. Eg 'vv-12' should loop 4 times. Fixed it with a nasty 4 IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, which i may not have done you could do:

```
$prod = strpos($input[$k] ['product'], "-");
if ($prod == '1'):
    $loop is null;
else:
    $loop is $prod;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array holding all elements except the ticket number.

Then for each ticket you copy this array and add the ticket number.

Unfortunately I did not find a better way to copy a PHP array than this:
http://php.net/manual/de/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php